# Firebase realtime db not able to filterdata with db only rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Firebase real time database.
I am trying to limit number of items returned from a query only by changing the db rrules on firebase
Is this possible? I dont want to change the app side code 
What is the rule if i have to fetch top 100 using the limittofirst.

Comment: did you try what I described in my answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase's server-side security rules merely determine whether a certain operation is allowed. They don't filter data by themselves.

If you want to retrieve the first 100 items, put a `limitToFirst(100)` in your query.

If you only ever want the first 100 items to be retrieved (as in: want other read operations to be rejected), have a look at the documentation on [securing queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules), which contains this example:

> You can also use query-based rules to limit how much data a client downloads through read operations.
>
> For example, the following rule limits read access to only the first 1000 results of a query, as ordered by priority:
>
> ```
> messages: {
>   ".read": "query.orderByKey &&
>             query.limitToFirst <= 1000"
> }
> ```
>
> Example queries:
>
> ```
> db.ref("messages").on("value", cb)                // Would fail with PermissionDenied
>
> db.ref("messages").limitToFirst(1000)
>                   .on("value", cb)                // Would succeed (default order by key)
> ```